# Injecting Angular 8 app with Chrome Extension Content Script

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension in Angular 8 like [AMZScout Pro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amzscout-pro/njopapoodmifmcogpingplfphojnfeea?hl=en) and I followed tutorial on this [blog](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/chrome-extension-with-angular-why-and-how-778200b87575), however, this is working as well but as popup behaviour.

What I want is to inject whole angular app into the visiting website and that what exactly AMZScout Pro does but problem is I don't know how to bootstrap angular 8 application and use it in [content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Also, another question is that what will be the best framework to have chrome extension like [AMZScout Pro](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amzscout-pro/njopapoodmifmcogpingplfphojnfeea?hl=en)?

Comment: What does this have to do with vue or react?

Comment: I had asked another question to choose the appropriate framework to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

create a `web_accessible_resource` in your manifest, and add an html page to it.

Then, in your content script create an iframe, and set `chrome.runtime.getURL('path/to/page.html')` as its source.

in your `page.html`, add a script tag to bootstrap your Angular app.

Comment: Can you please tell how to bootstrap angular app?

Comment: just copy your existing `index.html` file from your angular project and reference it in the iframe. It should work.

Comment: if you have it hosted somewhere, you can also just add that url as `src` for the iframe.

Comment: I get: Uncaught TypeError: chrome.extension.getURL is not a function

Comment: @titusfx `chrome.extension.getURL` is deprecated. You should use `chrome.runtime.getURL` now. I have updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @HammadAkhwand I did indeed, I forgot to comment here.

Comment: could you share how you are creating an iframe and setting its url in your contentScript?